# How to make the name of an organic group unique

Tags: organic-groups

can someone explain how to make groupnames unique? If i create 2 groups with the same name, i want to become a validation error. Actually i tested og in the commons distribution an there i can create groups with same names, but in the list of all groups are only one of the same groups listed.

Thanks for your help.

Greats Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your og groups are based on node entities.

> - You can have unique group titles with help of [unique_field](https://drupal.org/project/unique_field) module.
> - With help of this module you can set the title field as unique fields the content type generating groups on your site.

Comment: I will have a look at this module. But i am not sure if a unique check of a string field is case insensitive. For example 2 groups named "group_a" and "group_A" they are unique but just because the chaeck is case sensitive. Is there a way to say that the unique check should be case insensitive?

Comment: Could it be an option to call a validation function before saving the organic group entity? Where i can programmatically perform a unique check?

Comment: It pretty much depends on type of database you are using, if its mysql then go ahead and give a try to this module.

Comment: The reason I am saying is
node title field in database is varchar(that means , nonbinary string comparison i.e. case insensitive) and utf_general_ci (ci itself says case insensitive).

Comment: ok, thank you. I have check the database setting and you are right. So i will try it with the unique_field module.